# Can WCF Services be hosted on a Browser Helper Object?

Tags: wcf, bho

I am writting a silverlight programming which may interact with local win32 api, I want use a BHO hosting a wcf services as a mediator between native win32 api and silverlight application in browser. Can WCF Services be hosted on a Browser Helper Object?

Answer (score 0):

actually, you can host the service in any **managed** application. 
Why you want to use the WCF services as a mediator between native win32 API?
I'm not familiar with the BHO, if you really want to do this and BHO is unmanaged, you may wrap the BHO in managed code.